# Using upsert with simpleschema returns null with no collection inserts

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

Hey guys I'm trying to use Meteor upsert like so.

```
console.log(vendorReviewArr);
var updateQuery = {$set: {vendorID: vendorIDVal}, $push: {reviews:vendorReviewArr}};

VendorReviews.upsert(
    {vendorID: vendorIDVal},
    updateQuery,
    function(error){
        console.log("There is an error!");
        console.log(error);
        console.log("VENDOR ID: "+vendorIDVal);
    }
);
```

vendorReviewArr looks like this in console.log

```
{ title: 'This is a test title title title',
body: 'This is a test title body' }
```

Here is my simpleschema for VendorReviews.

```
VendorReviews = new Mongo.Collection('vendorsReviews'); //Define the collection.

VendorReviewObjSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    authorID: {
        type: String,
        label: "authorID",
        autoValue: function(){
            return this.userId
        },
        optional: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: "title",
        min: 25,
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        label: "body",
        min: 25,
        max: 1000
    }
});

VendorReviewsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    vendorID: {
        type: String,
        label: "vendorID HERE",

    },
    reviews : {
        type : [VendorReviewObjSchema],
        label : "Vendor Reviews",
        optional: true
    }

});

VendorReviews.attachSchema(VendorReviewsSchema);
```

Now for some reason when this method is called from the server the collection doesn't record any data. All I see is

```
I20160110-23:54:38.031(-5)? There is an error!
I20160110-23:54:38.032(-5)? null
I20160110-23:54:38.032(-5)? VENDOR ID: iXdqzcSNmMwrRj3jf
```

Checking the collection in mongo shell shows no data.

Can anyone help me out with this please? Thank you for reading.

Comment: put console.log(err), so that you can see exactly what error mongodb is throwing

Comment: @Poorna I did, function(error){}, as stated the error returns a null on console.